# C++ Error when using virtual destructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual-destructor

I have implemented an interface:

```
class ISolution
{
public:
  virtual ~ISolution() = 0;

  virtual void resultat() = 0;
};
```

and some derived classes from it:

```
class SolX : ISolution
{
private:
  int member;
  MyClass myOb;
public:
  SolX(const MyClass& inOb) : myOb(inOb) {}
  ~SolX() {}

  void resultat()
  {
    // the body
  }
};
```

When I compile it I get errors like:

```
/proj/CSolution1.cpp:4: undefined reference to `ISolution::~ISolution()'
/proj/CSolution2.cpp:4: undefined reference to `ISolution::~ISolution()'
CMakeFiles/proj.dir/CSolution2.cpp.o:/proj/CSolution2.cpp:12: more undefined references to `ISolution::~ISolution()' follow
```

I am using CMake and Linux Ubuntu.

I cannot figure out what is the problem. Is there something that I have missed? Does `myOb` create the problems?

P.S.: The line where is the error is at the definition of the constructor.

Comment: You can't have an abstract destructor. If you have a virtual destructor it will be called, and if it's abstract (doesn't have an implementation) how could it be called?

Comment: CMake isn't a compiler -- it's a build system.  Since you're in Linux, it's possible the compiler you're using is g++.

Comment: I know that CMake is not the compiler, sorry about the bad formulation of that sentence

Comment: @JohnDibling It could be argued that CMake isn't a build system either, but a build system generator. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is

```
virtual ~ISolution() = 0;
```

the destructor is not implemented.
Try

```
virtual ~ISolution() { }
```

instead.

This is needed even when only instances of the derived class are created, because destructors are special.
In a normal function, the base class implementation needs to be called explicitly, like

```
void Derived::Foo() {
    Base::Foo();
    ....
}
```

but for a destructor, this is always done automatically.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C++ Standard

> 9 A destructor can be declared virtual (10.3) or pure virtual (10.4);
>   if any objects of that class or any derived class are created in the
>   program, the destructor shall be defined.

So you have to define the destructor of the base class because it is called from the destructor of the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

A pure `virtual` destructor still needs a base class implementation.  At least it does in this case, because without it you can't `delete` the object.

Although not intuitive, this is a fairly common paradigm when implementing polymorphic base classes.

In some file, perhaps `isolutiuon.cpp`, implement:

```
ISolution::~ISolution()
{
}
```